# WIfi-Direct not working in rtl8812au drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless

I am using RTL8812AU based chipset USB Wi-Fi Adapter (Like ASUS AC56 , Linksys WUSB6300) in ubuntu (tried in different OS and Kernel version).
And I am trying to make use of WI-Fi Direct using wpa_supplicant (P2P Enabled) with user app wpa_cli.
In case of Intel Wireless Driver, whenever I do P2P_FIND or any scan command, from wpa_cli, my device is visible in any Wi-Fi Direct supported devices like Android, Windows etc.
But in case of Realtek driver (rtl8812au), my device is not visible or listed in Wi-Fi Direct device list, whereas I can get the nearby peers available in my device. As well I am able to connect to any SSID available.
So, am I missing something additional setup required for driver to make my device visible to other peer?
Any help would be very helpful?

**Please note**

I have tried every possible driver of rtl8812au available out there for Linux, only after that I am posting this question in seek of a answer.

1)https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU/

2)https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/

3)https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/

etc....

Thank you,

Comment: Please try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135744/wifi-is-unclaimed-rtl8821ce

Comment: My wifi is working fine, the issue is with wifi-direct.